# NSTask is not launching Python with correct path

Tags: python, xcode, cocoa, frameworks

In my Mac OS app I am including a Python.framework (v 2.7), so I added it to 'Linked frameworks' as Required. Also in the app, I am launching a Python script with NSTask like:

```
//...
pythonEnv = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] privateFrameworksPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python"];
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
outPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
readHandle = [outPipe fileHandleForReading];
data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: scriptPath, kbt, server, port, username, password, nil];

[task setArguments:args];
[task setLaunchPath: pythonEnv];

readHandle = [outPipe fileHandleForReading];
[task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];
[task setStandardOutput:outPipe];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
//...
```

When I build the app, and in Python script check to see which version it uses with `sys.path`, it returns:

["/Users/...path to script.../Contents/Resources", "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip", "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7", "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin", "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac", "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages", "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk", "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old", "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload", "/Users/tatiana/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages", "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages", "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages"]

... it's not using my included framework. Where else should I be setting the correct path? Is it something in Build Settings I am forgetting?

**UPDATE 1 ------------------------**

If I don't set task environment, and in Python test with `sys.executable`, I get:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

... so it looks like it's not using my framework. If set task environment with:

```
// pythonEnv = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] privateFrameworksPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python"];
NSDictionary *environment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: pythonEnv, @"PYTHONPATH", nil];
[task setEnvironment:environment];
```

and test it, I still get the same result. BUT, if in Python I test with `os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]`, I get:

/Users/tatiana/Desktop/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

That looks a bit more promissing, but I am confused why sys.executable is not giving me that.

**UPDATE 2**

My **bin/python** was not an executable, so I changed it to python2.7; `sys.executable` still shows that it defaults to Library/...

```
pythonEnv = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] privateFrameworksPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7"];
NSString *searchPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] privateFrameworksPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7"];
NSDictionary *environment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: searchPath, @"PYTHONPATH", nil];
[task setEnvironment:environment];
```

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but you should use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` when you want to staple paths together. It more clearly expresses what you're doing.

Comment: You've just showed us how you've set the launch path - how do you launch the script? Suppose we need more of your code to be able to help you out

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're confusing two related things:

1. Launching the Python executable that's inside the app bundle
2. Setting the Python search path to include the Python lib folder that's inside the app bundle

To set the path of the Python executable that `NSTask` runs, set its `launchPath`. In Python you can access the value using `sys.executable`.

To manipulate Python's search path, invoke `-[NSTask setEnvironment:]` with `PYTHONPATH` set to **your framework's `lib/python2.7` folder**. In Python you can access that path with `sys.path`.

Comment: I rewrote my answer to try to clarify. Have you verified that `/Users/tatiana/Desktop/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` actually is a python executable and not a symlink?

Comment: you're right, python i was linking to was just an alias. I made some updates.

Comment: added it via 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries'... (I downloaded it form python.org I think??)

Comment: Oh, so you aren't building the framework. Why then are you copying it into your app bundle?

Comment: because I am stupid, I thought you can! 
ok. back to the drawing board.

Comment: (i thought when you search for one to link, Xcode finds "framework" builds, and I assumed that was it)

Comment: I'm lost. Linking to a framework is totally different from invoking a process using NSTask. It'd be easier to answer you question if it were clearer what you were actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well, since I don't know which version of python users might have, I want to include 2.7 with my app. This python script I am launching  via NSTask, and it simply checks mail and returns results to the app. I want to be sure that the script is running from my bundled framework, and not user's default.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a known bug. See this [old mailing list post](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2001-November/008487.html) and this [much more recent bug on bugs.python.org](http://bugs.python.org/issue7774).

There's this comment in Modules/getpath.c of Python 2.7.3:

```
 /* On Mac OS X, if a script uses an interpreter of the form
  * "#!/opt/python2.3/bin/python", the kernel only passes "python"
  * as argv[0], which falls through to the $PATH search below.
  * If /opt/python2.3/bin isn't in your path, or is near the end,
  * this algorithm may incorrectly find /usr/bin/python. To work
  * around this, we can use _NSGetExecutablePath to get a better
  * hint of what the intended interpreter was, although this
  * will fail if a relative path was used. but in that case,
  * absolutize() should help us out below
  */
```

While this may not apply directly to you, this is a hint that maybe `argv[0]` in the executed python process is just `"python"`. Python will then look at `$PATH` and try to find the absolute path to the Python interpreter if the `_NSGetExecutablePath` hack mentioned in the comment fails or is not present in your version. Your framework, not being in `$PATH`, is ignored, so it finds the system Python and uses that.

You could verify this a couple ways. You could set a breakpoint in a debugger and look at the arguments that `NSTask` eventually passes to `exec()`. Or, you may be able to look at `ps ax` and find your Python process (it may help to have your script print its PID and then run forever) and see if the first argument is the full path to your framework. Or, you could check out `sys.argv[0]` in your script (probably -- maybe it's modified).

If this is indeed the problem, the fix is to get a proper `argv[0]` set. I don't see a way to do that with `NSTask`, so your next best bet is probably to include the path to your Python framework's `bin/` in the `PATH` environment variable. At least then Python may infer the correct value for `sys.executable`.

Or, if nothing in your script really cares about `sys.executable`, you could just leave it as is after you have determined that your Python is in fact the one being executed, dispite `sys.executable`.

Comment: Also, I intended to suggest you try [invoking libpython directly](http://docs.python.org/2.7/extending/embedding.html#very-high-level-embedding) rather than executing the Python interpreter. It's a little more code to set up, but ultimately you will have better control over the Python environment, and can do neater things.