# Trying to run cli with NSTask is failing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstask

I am trying to run the following in a cocoa app:

cat PATHTOFILE | python -mjson.tool > OUTPUTFILE

```
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/cat"];

    NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObject: path];
    [task setArguments: arguments];

    NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput:pipe];
    [task launch];

    NSTask *task2 = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task2 setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/python"];
    NSArray *arguments2 = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"-mjson.tool > %@.beautify", path]];
    [task2 setArguments:arguments2];
    [task2 setStandardInput:pipe];

    NSPipe *pipe2 = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task2 setStandardOutput:pipe2];
    [task2 launch];
```

However I am getting the following error:
    /usr/bin/python: Import by filename is not supported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems more like a Python error.

`/usr/bin/python -mjson.tool`calls the following file : (when used from terminal)

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/tool.py`

whose content is

```
""" headers..."""
import sys
import json

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        infile = sys.stdin
        outfile = sys.stdout
    elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
        infile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
        outfile = sys.stdout
    elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
        infile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
        outfile = open(sys.argv[2], 'wb')
    else:
        raise SystemExit(sys.argv[0] + " [infile [outfile]]")
    try:
        obj = json.load(infile)
    except ValueError, e:
        raise SystemExit(e)
    json.dump(obj, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    outfile.write('\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You task can't resolve these import statements. Surely because it doesn't know as much as the terminal does, and can't find this...
See [NSTask is not launching Python with correct path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026634/nstask-is-not-launching-python-with-correct-path/14048100#14048100)